# Viewport Not Rendering/No Lights/No Materials

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, lighting, denoise

I just did a render 2 min ago. I'm on blender 2.9 and I was playing around with the denoise features. At the time, the lighting was working, and the materials on my object were perfectly fine. I was using Cycles to render in the viewport. So I decided to try a render with the denoising, and the message "Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time". It took way too long for being worth the wait so i just knew i just saved my project, and i alt f4'd. So i relaunch the program, and when I load my project, lighting, materials and none of the rendering engines want to even work. I hit F12 to run a render, and it works there, but not in my viewport. What's going on?

[image]

Comment: You are in solid preview mode. Change to material preview or rendered preview (two farthest right of the 4 small circles in the top right of the viewport). You can also switch modes by pressing the hotkey Z in the 3D viewport and then selecting your preview mode from the pie menu.

Comment: Can you make it a little  more clear a bit I don't understand what's your question?